# sql join with count and group

Tags: sql

Would you please be able to help me on this SQL issue?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         SERIAL,ID,NAME,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM1 
     FROM TABLE_1) AS X
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         PROGRAM, COLOR, PART, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM2 
     FROM TABLE_2) AS Y ON X.NUM1 = Y.NUM2
```

and output is

```
Serial  ID#  Name  Num1 Program     Color     part   Num2
---------------------------------------------------------
105057  8    A1     1   Basketball  Blue      12      1
104552  9    B2     2   Soccer      Yellow    15      2
104552  9    B2     3   Soccer      Yellow    15      3
104956  9    B2     4   Soccer      Yellow    15      4 
104956  8    A1     5   Basketball  Blue      12      5
```

How can I count and group them in terms of the full join. My output should be as;

```
Serial  ID#  Name   Program     Color     part   Total
------------------------------------------------------
105057  8    A1     Basketball  Blue       12      2 
104552  9    B2     Soccer      Yellow     15      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `select` the columns and then `group by` all of them.

```
SELECT
min(x.serial), x.id, x.name,
y.program, y.color, y.part, count(*) as total
FROM
(SELECT  SERIAL,ID,NAME,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM1 FROM TABLE_1) AS X
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT PROGRAM,COLOR,PART, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM2 FROM TABLE_2) AS Y
ON X.NUM1 = Y.NUM2 
group by x.id, x.name, x.num1,
y.program, y.color, y.part, y.num2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group repeated columns and use a function to choose Serial and to get the Total.

```
SELECT MAX(Serial) as Serial, ID, Name, Program, Color, Part, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM
(SELECT SERIAL, ID, NAME,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM1 FROM TABLE_1) AS X
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT PROGRAM,COLOR,PART, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM2 FROM TABLE_2) AS Y
ON X.NUM1 = Y.NUM2
GROUP BY ID, Name, Program, Color, Part
```